# Mouse clicking not working on Disk Utility screen. How do I select erase button?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

When I returned home a couple days ago, I had a notification that some updates had been installed. This had rendered my 27" iMac basically useless. It lags horrendously with almost a never ending spinning beach ball cursor.

I'm trying to delete the HDD contents and reinstall the os, but when I boot to Recovery Mode to get to the Utilities screen, the mouse pointer will move but it will not click. I was able to figure out how to use the keyboard to get to the Disk Utility section but I cannot find out how highlight the erase button using the keyboard. If someone can come up with an answer or easier method, I'd be forever in your debt.

Comment: Are you using a USB mouse or a wireless mouse?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select a drive and erase it. However, while you've worked out how to select the drive using the keyboard, you're not able to select the Erase button.

In your situation you can do this with by using the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

Hope this helps. If I've misunderstood your question, please let me know.

Comment: Ahhh jeez. Now I'm to the screen on the sierra install steps where you select what drive you want to install the os on. The hd is already chosen but I don't know how to select "install"

Comment: What happens if you press the Tab key? Does it cycle through the the various options? If so, when you see the Install button selected, press Enter.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. Macintosh hd is highlighted. I just can't figure out how to get to the back/install options.

Comment: My first thoughts are to just hit enter and see what happens? Also try the right-arrow key. And finally, pressing on the 'i' key. Any luck with any of those?

Comment: No luck. I wonder if a USB mouse would make any difference.

Comment: Yes! You really need to have a functioning Mouse to make this easier. It's not clear from your question what kind of mouse you have or why it's not clicking, but connecting a functioning USB mouse will work!